# How Can I Display Multi-Value Columns in Pandas Chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got a 4 dataframes with different values:

```
        CAND
YES        5
NO         0
        MARK
YES        4
NO         1
        TRBL
YES        0
NO         0
      STATUS
Inactive   3
Active     2
```

Ideally I'd like a bar chart where the X axis has 2 bars for each DF (since there's 2 possible values per DF) and the Y axis is the total count for each. I've scoured through the Pandas Visualization documentation but it's dealing primarily with numbers and displaying values for one specific column of a worksheet or dataframe whereas I'm trying to show multiple values from multiple dataframes in one bar chart.

This does need to be embedded into an HTML email as well. Is this possible or am I dreaming up something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 4 dataFrames defines as `df1, df2, df3, df4`
Plot them in one chart this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

df1.plot(kind = bar, ax=axes[0,0])
df2.plot(kind = bar, ax=axes[0,1])
df3.plot(kind = bar, ax=axes[1,0])
df4.plot(kind = bar, ax=axes[1,1])
```

Comment: Nice! This is pretty much what I was looking for! With the continuation of the plots, though, for df3, the axes won't be `[0,2]` right? What will that be?